# Square root a number

Tags: code-golf, math, abstract-algebra, restricted-time

The task is as follows: Given a positive integer `x` and a prime `n > x`, output the smallest positive integer `y` such that `(y * y) mod n = x`.  An  important part of this question is the time limit specified below which excludes brute force solutions.

If there is no such value `y` then your code should output `N`.

**Test cases**

```
(2, 5, N), 
(3, 5, N), 
(4, 5, 2),
(524291, 1048583, N),
(529533, 1048583, N),
(534775, 1048583, 436853),
(540017, 1048583, 73675),
(536870913, 1073741827, 375394238),
(542239622, 1073741827, 267746399),
(547608331, 1073741827, N),
(552977040, 1073741827, 104595351),
(1099511627676, 1099511627791, N),
(1099511627677, 1099511627791, 269691261521),
(1099511627678, 1099511627791, 413834069585),
(1267650600228229401496703204376, 1267650600228229401496703205653, 5312823546347991512233563776),
(1267650600228229401496703204476, 1267650600228229401496703205653, N)
(1267650600228229401496703204576, 1267650600228229401496703205653, N)
(1267650600228229401496703204676, 1267650600228229401496703205653, 79905476259539917812907012931)
```

**Input and output**

You may take input and give output in any way that is convenient. If you don't like to output `N` then any `Falsey` value will do.

**Restrictions**

Your code must answer all the test cases in under 1 minute on a standard desktop. This time limit is only to prevent brute force answers and I expect good answers to run almost instantly. You may not use any library or builtin that solves this problem or that tests if a number is a quadratic residue.

Comment: So languages without support for big-integer data type are ruled out. Pity

Comment: @LuisMendo Not if you can code up support for `1267650600228229401496703205653` yourself or if you have 128 bit support such as `__int128` in gcc. There are also a number of 256 bit int libraries out there for various languages. Last, lots of languages have an arbitrary precision int library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>83</s> 82 bytes

```
=eAQM.^GHQKf%=/H=2;1=gftgT/Q;1HJg~gGHh/H2WtG=*J=gT^2t-K=Kfq1gG^2T1=%*G=^T2Q;hS%_BJ
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3DeAQM.%5EGHQKf%25%3D%2FH%3D2%3B1%3DgftgT%2FQ%3B1HJg~gGHh%2FH2WtG%3D%2aJ%3DgT%5E2t-K%3DKfq1gG%5E2T1%3D%25%2aG%3D%5ET2Q%3BhS%25_BJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%2C+2%0A2%2C+5%0A524291%2C+1048583%0A536870913%2C+1073741827%0A1099511627676%2C+1099511627791%0A1267650600228229401496703204376%2C+1267650600228229401496703205653%0A1267650600228229401496703204476%2C+1267650600228229401496703205653&debug=0)

This program implements the [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm). I wrote it by closely following the Wikipedia page. It takes as input `(n, p)`.

The absence of a square root is reported by the following error:

```
TypeError: pow() 3rd argument not allowed unless all arguments are integers
```

---

This is very intricately golfed code, written in the imperative style, as opposed to the more common functional style of Pyth.

The one subtle aspect of Pyth I'm using is `=`, which, if not immediately followed by a variable, searches forward in the program for the next variable, then assigns the result of the following expression to that variable, then returns that result. I will refer throughout the explanation to the wikipedia page: [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm), as that is the algorithm I am implementing.

**Explanation:**

```
=eAQ
```

`A` takes a 2-tuple as input, and assigns the values to `G` and `H` respectively, and returns its input. `Q` is the initial input. `e` returns the last element of a sequence. After this snippet, `G` is `n`, and `H` and `Q` are `p`.

```
M.^GHQ
```

`M` defines a 2 input function `g`, where the inputs are `G` and `H`. `.^` is Pyth's fast modular exponentiation function. This snippet defines `g` to mean exponentiation mod `Q`.

```
Kf%=/H=2;1
```

`f` defines a repeat until false loop, and returns the number of iterations it runs for, given `1` as its input. During each iteration of the loop, we divide `H` by 2, set `H` to that value, and check whether the result is odd. Once it is, we stop. `K` stores the number of iterations this took.

One very tricky thing is the `=2;` bit. `=` searches ahead for the next variable, which is `T`, so `T` is set to 2. However, `T` inside an `f` loop is the iteration counter, so we use `;` to get the value of `T` from the global environment. This is done to save a couple of bytes of whitespace that would otherwise be needed to separate the numbers.

After this snippet, `K` is `S` from the wikipedia article (wiki), and `H` is `Q` from the wiki, and `T` is `2`.

```
=gftgT/Q;1H
```

Now, we need to find a quadratic nonresidue mod `p`. We'll brute force this using the Euler criterion. `/Q2` is `(p-1)/2`, since `/` is floored division, so `ftgT/Q;1` finds the first integer `T` where `T ^ ((p-1)/2) != 1`, as desired. Recall that `;` again pulls `T` from the global environment, which is still 2. This result is `z` from the wiki.

Next, to create `c` from the wiki, we need `z^Q`, so we wrap the above in `g ... H` and assign the result to `T`. Now `T` is `c` from the wiki.

```
Jg~gGHh/H2
```

Let's separate out this: `~gGH`. `~` is like `=`, but returns the original value of the variable, not its new value. Thus, it returns `G`, which is `n` from the wiki.

This assigns `J` the value of `n^((Q+1)/2)`, which is `R` from the wiki.

Now, the following takes effect:

```
~gGH
```

This assigns `G` the value `n^Q`, which is `t` from the wiki.

Now, we have our loop variables set up. `M, c, t, R` from the wiki are `K, T, G, J`.

The body of the loop is complicated, so I'm going to present it with the whitespace, the way I wrote it:

```
WtG
  =*J
    =
      gT^2
        t-
          K
          =Kfq1gG^2T1
  =%*G=^T2Q;
```

First, we check whether `G` is 1. If so, we exit the loop.

The next code that runs is:

```
=Kfq1gG^2T1
```

Here, we search for the first value of `i` such that `G^(2^i) mod Q = 1`, starting at 1. The result is saved in `K`.

```
=gT^2t-K=Kfq1gG^2T1
```

Here, we take the old value of `K`, subtract the new value of `K`, subtract 1, raise 2 to that power, and then raise `T` to that power mod `Q`, and then assign the result to `T`. This makes `T` equal to `b` from the wiki.

This is also the line which terminates the loop and fails if there is no solution, because in that case the new value of `K` will equal the old value of `K`, 2 will be raised to the `-1`, and the modular exponentiation will raise an error.

```
=*J
```

Next, we multiply `J` by the above result and store it back in `J`, keeping `R` updated.

```
=^T2
```

Then we square `T` and store the result back in `T`, setting `T` back to `c` from the wiki.

```
=%*G=^T2Q
```

Then we multiply `G` by that result, take it mod `Q` and store the result back in `G`.

```
;
```

And we terminate the loop.

After the loop's over, `J` is a square root of `n` mod `p`. To find the smallest one, we use the following code:

```
hS%_BJ
```

`_BJ` creates the list of `J` and its negation, `%` implicitly takes `Q` as its second argument, and uses the default behavior of Pyth to apply `% ... Q` to each member of the sequence. Then `S` sorts the list and `h` takes its first member, the minimum.

Answer (score 11):

## Python 2, 166 bytes

```py
def Q(x,n,a=0):
 e=n/2
 while pow(a*a-x,e,n)<2:a+=1
 w=a*a-x;b=r=a;c=s=1
 while e:
    if e%2:r,s=(r*b+s*c*w)%n,r*c+s*b
    b,c=(b*b+c*c*w)%n,2*b*c;e/=2
 return min(r,-r%n)
```

Comment: `%timeit Q(1267650600228229401496703204676,1267650600228229401496703205653)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.83 ms per loop`  :)

Comment: What a great answer! You have restored my faith in PPCG.

Comment: Excuse the newbie question, but whats PPCG? Polish Python Coders Group?

Comment: @DaveBoltman Programming Puzzles & Code Golf.

Answer (score 6):

## [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/), 93 bytes

By reduction to a [much harder problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) for which SageMath happens to have fast enough builtins.

```python
def f(x,n):g=primitive_root(n);k=Zmod(n)(x).log(g);y=pow(g,k//2,n);return k%2<1and min(y,n-y)
```

[Try it on SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJytjt1KxDAQRu8F36E3QgrVnZ8kk1j7It6I0G4p3SZLqbp9e-OCYKGVXuzdfJxvzkzdHLOjuhQhf26r89gN3dR9Nm9jjJMKedlXr0Os06Qu-dMptqrNy7k6xy_VFv3hQGmvHJvpYwxZ_0Av-B7qbOiCmovwOOf3d8kYpnSAisz8ibyMehkNafJYZAjaGccL4g3zKmEtYlaJBkBZ37FOwONVKCwaHclik4i9JdrkYsEx4xZP74qAhg2O4L1BtCRW7E_nN4rHjZrsq7l_apSOGbAARI7Ia0DtrQATaL6-sV0w1vBOlb6dytxOZfeovgGOjLkG&lang=sage)

Comment: That reduction is quite funny :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 326 bytes

Usually I like brute force answers.. Since this is strongly discouraged by the time limit, here's the most efficient way I know of:

```hs
r p=((\r->min(mod(-r)p)r)$).f p
f p x|p==2=x|q x=f 0 0|mod p 4==3=x&div(p+1)4|let(r,s)=foldl i(p-1,0)[1..t 1o]=m$x&(d$r+1)*(b&d s)where q a=1/=a&o;m=(`mod`p);a&0=1;a&e|even e=m$a&d e^2|0<1=m$(a&(e-1))*a;b=[n|n<-[2..],q n]!!0;i(a,b)_|m(x&d a*b&d b)==p-1=(d a,d b+o)|0<1=(d a,d b);o=d p;t y x|even x=t(y+1)(d x)|0<1=y;d=(`div`2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZRLc9owFIX3/IqbGYaREkP1lhWibDLdtZt2SWhiQDSe4keM25oZ/3d6cQIJTTrDogtrfDnfPTpXAh6S9Y@wWm3TrCyqGm6KvK6K1ehjMw9lnRZ5r5claQ4elqu0hCwpP0Md1vVNsg5r6MMtSaJZNKcwvIZF0QOo4WoIdbUBUoX6Z5VD/wwqmEFCUZxjFxLFEt8BvqTfH2oUsbWs0ryGzquKKu/ntCM@hWUN4S8gRHPv2RMA8PshVAHuMGC4vPxaZOFV8pegHukJEBGBjqDrjYDIo0p1lXiutFDC8Qg4U7GO5QumhdNSvidIZa1@JShpYi33qmKM21eqlcbqQ6uJLXO8s7XSKh4LZKXV0ikh44OHENIZIY4xYaxVRjp3wKxhsZT8GDvkxAmsZYodyxhM42SaP2OcOac5N8Iaa3byvrS7Y2HvUPYNJYwzjgvDtXjPNn7ToLiMpWLG6Xh/NthujWaGMSFiIZxiXDljmRRMyS7ZvwFt9O6OJUdBajwjZZ3jmuMxSm2kteaETdRJm7ATnPR/czInOeGwbPdlELuLxcFtzIVjluEqu/uYbisoPSG31fA6S3OSFQsyrGhJK9qnoyWUPXygaUvvhW/aR2j8EhiwFkEUlPfSN4NF@ouUF5yqdhVqUkVr6pfFarGClJRDHjE64aNRDbyY@qzfDMiiXyF9TmaDBazp0@/3ERLPP/hkUIwzT@7R/76k42TAPMc1tOFXyCFgf4JN4Zto2RXHiiQDEoac0vNkPPOTvM2vhhMxGk2jR8inZ2dsnO7@MuhdmxEMCsn5btMZ9R6TeYIfRFheFLTz29d0XHicb1zDBofvtm58TTaYGpHmCd6MFxgUZ78XdLv9Aw)

I'm sure this can be golfed down further, but this should do for now.

Comment: Could you modify the TIO code so it gives the answers as output? I just get "True" at the moment.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDBjpswEIbveYo/EkJ21lCg28uS2cuqt/bSHrPpxoBpUAE7xt0SiXdPZxNVrXqw5fF8M/7GRz39MH1/6QZnfcCTHYO3ffpxro0LnR1Xq0F3Iwht3zkM2n1GMFN40pOZEOFZaFWpWiJ5RGNXQMA2QfBnCG/CTz8iWsOjgpacrLmKCdvyGfjSfT8GTnKp890YcO3llSeq5ZX4ZNoA8x9gVE2U3QDg19F4gxcWNA8PX@1g/jH/K0pM7yAKhQ8KmcT@4uFIiGefPA7dKAbbiMRLJ72MZNrCrXhhXhxRQfNywkwtMmQLg5y4J3pPc9x0r8Ld5fJ@6U0QXk2SWts3PTrhklxlcpenaUBu9zREcyyayDO9EVXcYJI38xM05e9Ix7YcSBy4/8HJUscZ5bybxbyaEYbrNReZb8WSbXOOhI6FSXIpN7qsaDcu4zbZFWm6VyeM@/U6K7u3z5IvyyBYFHrz9mglidiMBF8oDu@svPb7E8vSEs9XBpx5@OvTMwVxZmtG5ht8LhsW5dkPhbxcfgM "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Lembik You need to replace `testCases` with those from the original TIO, it barely fit into a comment even without them.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks a lot! I adjusted my answer with your code and replaced  `testCases`.

Comment: Huh, I'm seeing a bizarre bug with that TIO link - if I click it it has the code but neither running nor getting the URL from the menu options works - *but* if I copy the URL from the address bar and paste it into a different tab, then it works.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Not sure.. On my machine it works as expected, have you tried other TIOs? Maybe NoScript or similar getting in your way?

Comment: I suspect some caching issue somewhere, because now it's working again.